# Battleship using JButtons

Tags: java, arrays, swing

Started making a battleship game using JButtons, knowing it would be a bit more difficult than simply drawing a graph, however I feel a bit more compelled to accomplish this feat with the given option. Anyway, I'm being thrown errors, and eclipse isn't proclaiming what those errors are. Could anyone decipher these, or at least get me close to figuring out my issue? EDIT: **Updated code is posted**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel lButton, rButton, textPan, turnPan;
    private JRadioButton turnC, turnP;
    private JTextArea jta;
    private static JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JRadioButton jrb;
    private static int SIZE = 10;
    private JButton[][] left, right;
    private int rand1, rand2;
    private int turnIndicator; //Allows the swap method to switch between player turn and computer turn 0 = player turn, 1 = computer turn
    public TestDemo(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        /** Buttons + Button Panels */
        lButton = new JPanel();
        lButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(SIZE,SIZE));
        rButton = new JPanel();
        rButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(SIZE,SIZE));
        left = new JButton[SIZE][SIZE];
        right = new JButton[SIZE][SIZE];
        turnIndicator = 0; 
        for (char row = 'A'; row <= 'J'; row++) 
            for (int col = 1, i = 0, j = 0; col <= 10 && i < SIZE && j < SIZE; col++, i++, j++) {
                left[i][j] = new JButton("" + row + col);
                right[i][j] = new JButton(""+row+col);
                left[i][j].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
                left[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                right[i][j].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
                right[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
                left[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                right[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                lButton.add(left[i][j]);
                rButton.add(right[i][j]);
            }//end for
        /** End of Buttons + Button panels */

        /** Text Area */
        jta = new JTextArea(5,25);
        jta.setLineWrap(true);
        jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        jta.setVisible(true);
        textPan = new JPanel();
        textPan.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        textPan.add(new JScrollPane(jta));
        /** End of Text Area */

        /** Turn radio button */
        turnC = new JRadioButton("Computer");
        turnC.addActionListener(this);
        turnC.setEnabled(false);
        turnP = new JRadioButton("Player");
        turnP.addActionListener(this);
        turnP.setEnabled(false);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(turnC);
        group.add(turnP);
        turnP.setSelected(true);
        turnPan = new JPanel();
        turnPan.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        turnPan.add(turnC, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        turnPan.add(turnP, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        /** End turn radio button and label */

        /** Menu setup */
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        JMenuItem newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game"); newGame.addActionListener(this);
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit"); exit.addActionListener(new exitApp());
        newGame.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N); exit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        newGame.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuBar.add(file);
        file.add(newGame); file.add(exit);
        /** End Menu setup */

        JPanel gameTest = new JPanel();
        gameTest.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gameTest.add(lButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        gameTest.add(rButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        gameTest.add(textPan, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        gameTest.add(turnPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(gameTest);  
    }//end TestDemo

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    TestDemo td = new TestDemo();
    frame.add(td);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}//end main

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();
    if(turnIndicator == 0)
    {

    turnP.setSelected(true);
    (pressed).setEnabled(false);
    jta.append("Shot fired at : " + (pressed).getActionCommand() + '\n' );
    turnIndicator = 1;
    } 
    turnC.setSelected(true);
    swap(); //Throwing an error

}//end actionPerformed

public void compAttk()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> key1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);
    ArrayList<Integer> key2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);
    rand1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    if(key1.contains(rand1) || key2.contains(rand2))/** Checks if the coords are already pressed*/
    {
        rand1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        right[rand1][rand2].setEnabled(false); //I'm sure will also throw an error
    }
    right[rand1][rand2].setEnabled(false); //Throwing an error
    key1.add(rand1);
    key2.add(rand2);
    turnIndicator = 0;
}//end compAttk

public void swap() //Once user presses a button, turnIndicator will initialize to 1, then this method handles what happens afterwards.
{
    if(turnIndicator == 1)
    {
        compAttk(); //Throwing an error
        turnIndicator = 0;
    }
    else
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your turn");
}//end swap
static class exitApp implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}//end exitApp
}//end TestDemo class


Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at TestDemo.compAttk(TestDemo.java:91)
at TestDemo.swap(TestDemo.java:103)
at TestDemo.actionPerformed(TestDemo.java:70)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you should replace `rand1 = (int) (Math.random() + 10);` with `rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);`

The way it is written now you always get a random number of 10 which is not what you expect, I suppose.

The other thing here is that if your ArrayList holds 10 elements, its last index is 9, not 10. Here is where `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` comes from.

Comment: It's late (My excuse for having a + instead of * in my random number generator). The thing about the arraylist. No I don't want just 10, I want random int between 1-10 for the row & col of buttons.

Comment: @jeffreyzachary, replacing `+` with `*` should fix the exception unless there are more issues with your code. Having `+` instead of `*` makes your random generator always return 10, which is out of bounds for the array.

Comment: Right, yea it got rid of those errors. My 3 biggest issues are the error I'm receiving for my `swap();` method, how I'm calling `right[rand1][rand2].setEnabled(false);` and the error when I call `compAttk();` in the `swap();` method. I'm not sure at all if the other errors about java.awt and such will go away after those 3, but at least that will give me some breathing room knowing I've resolved my method errors.

Comment: Well, still no luck figuring this out, however, for being the only answerer to at least attempt to resolve my issue, I'll give you the best answer. Thanks bud! Still a beginner programmer, so I'm learning more and more as I go.

Comment: @jeffreyzachary, this question refers the error which has been solved. If you have other issues, you should start new questions for them.

Comment: The question refers to the list of errors I posted. Out of all the errors, the only 1 to get resolved was the arrayIndexOutOfBounds, so yes, I up voted you and marked yours as the best answer. I'm thankful for it, and sooner or later I'll figure out what's wrong with my methods or how I'm calling my methods.